# Vertical overflow always showing scrollbar which never works

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have a sidebar with a menu with icons. When it overflows vertically you should be able to scroll the menu vertically so I am using `overflow-y: scroll` and the parent has `overflow-y` auto. However, scrolling is not working at all.

- the scroll bar is always showing, even when the content isn't overflowing (just try removing half of the list items in my fiddle and you'll see what I mean)
- the scroll bar is simply not functional. It appears locked and you can't really drag it to scroll up and down the menu.

[Here is a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kpagcha/29fqauLy/23/).

Note I've tried with `overflow-y: auto` but [it doesn't work either](https://jsfiddle.net/kpagcha/29fqauLy/21/).

Also, the last three links should be pushed to be bottom of the sidebar (if there is enough space). For that, I'm using `margin-top: auto` on the first item of the group.

HTML:

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="sidebar-head">H</div>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="">6</a></li>
    <li class="bottom"><a href="">7</a></li>
    <li><a href="">8</a></li>
    <li><a href="">9</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sidebar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    box-shadow: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding-top: 70px;
    width: 230px;
    overflow-x: visible;
    overflow-y: auto;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #222d32;
    transition: left 0.3s ease, width 0.3s ease;
    left: 0;
    width: 50px;
}

.sidebar-head {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #fff;
}

.menu {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex: 1;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.menu > li {
  width: 100%;
}

.menu > li > a {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 12px 15px;
    font-size: 1.08em;
    border-left: 3px solid transparent;
    transition: border-left-color 0.3s ease, background-color 0.3s ease;
    color: #fff;
    background: #0d1214;
    border-left-color: #009688;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.bottom {
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and not a link to your site or any third party site.

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was `flex-wrap: wrap` in `.menu`. As soon as I removed it, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

It is becaouse You have given `overflow-y:scroll` for the list with class `menu`. Changing it to `overflow-y:auto` will fix it.

Here's the corrected fiddle:
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gq2dw05y/)

Comment: I was just editing my question. I tried `overflow: auto` as well but it wasn't scrolling either.

Comment: Did you check the fiddle in the answer??

Comment: Yes, it's exactly like the second fiddle in my original question.

Comment: I don't want to rely on fixed heights.

Answer (score 0):

You've used Flexbox for every container. There is no need to use `display: flex` on the `.sidebar` element. Change it to `display: block` or remove the whole display definition and it'll scroll.

Check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/vns3gyf7/

Answer (score 0):

I updated `.menu` in your fiddle and it works.

```
.menu {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: This is the closest it gets to working. There's a problem though. The last few list items should actually be at the bottom of the sidebar. With your solution they're not. I updated my original question with the extras.